# nvd3 piechart.js - How to edit the tooltip?

Tags: javascript, tooltip, d3.js, pie-chart, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3's piechart.js component to generate a piechart on my site. The provided .js file includes several var's, as follows:

```
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20}
    , width = null
    , height = null
    , showLegend = true
    , color = nv.utils.defaultColor()
    , tooltips = true
    , tooltip = function(key, y, e, graph) {
        return '<h3>' + key + '</h3>' +
               '<p>' +  y + '</p>'
      }
    , noData = "No Data Available."
    , dispatch = d3.dispatch('tooltipShow', 'tooltipHide')
;
```

In my in-line js, I've been able to override some of those variables, like this (overriding showLegend and margin):

```
var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
    .x(function(d) { return d.label })
    .y(function(d) { return d.value })
    .showLabels(false)
    .showLegend(false)
    .margin({top: 10, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0})
    .donut(true);
```

I've tried overwriting the tooltip in the same way:

```
.tooltip(function(key, y, e, graph) { return 'Some String' })
```

but when I do that, my piechart does not display at all. Why can't I overwrite the tooltip here? Is there another way I can do so? I'd really rather not have to edit piechart.js itself at all; I need to keep that file generic for use in multiple widgets.

And while we're at it, is there some way I can make the entire tooltip into a clickable link?

Comment: I'm not nvd3 expert, just started playing with it. I had the same problem as you, what you're looking for is : .tooltipContent(function(key, y, e, graph) { return 'Some String' }) *And while we're at it, is there some way I can make the entire tooltip
into a clickable link?* You can return any HTML for the tooltip, but as it appear/disappears on hover, you'll have a hard time clicking on it.

Answer (score 56):

Just override in this way it will work definitely

```
function tooltipContent(key, y, e, graph) {
            return '<h3>' + key + '</h3>' +'<p>' + y + '</p>' ;
        }
```

Or

```
tooltipContent(function(key, y, e, graph) { return 'Some String' })
```

Comment: +1 for the alternative solution. I have been using `.tooltip(..)` for a lot of NVD3 charts, and just had to use `.tooltipContent(..)` for the lineChart.js

Comment: can you please tell me, how I can modify this method for NVD3's linechart coz tooltipcontent is not working in that case?

Comment: @MitakshGupta `tooltipContent` is deprecated, use `chart.tooltip.contentGenerator` instead

Answer (score 42):

I have just got the same problem, with nvd3 1.8.1, and this is the solution I've found.

Without the option `useInteractiveGuideline` you could simply declare your tooltip generating function in `chart.tooltip.contentGenerator(function (d){ YOUR_FUNCTION_HERE})`:

The argument `d` is given by nvd3 when calling the tooltip, and it has three properties :

- `value`: the x-axis value for the cursor position
- `index`: the index in chart's `datum` corresponding to the the cursor position
- `series`: an array containing, for each item in the chart :

  - `key`: the legend key for that item
  - `value`: the y-axis value for that item at the cursor position
  - `color`: the legend color for that item

So here you have an example:

```
chart.tooltip.contentGenerator(function (d) {
          var html = "<h2>"+d.value+"</h2> <ul>";

          d.series.forEach(function(elem){
            html += "<li><h3 style='color:"+elem.color+"'>"
                    +elem.key+"</h3> : <b>"+elem.value+"</b></li>";
          })
          html += "</ul>"
          return html;
        })
```

**Important note**

When the option `useInteractiveGuideline` is used, the `chart.tooltip` object isn't used to generate the tooltip,  you must instead use the `chart.interactiveLayer.tooltip`, i.e.:

```
this.chart.interactiveLayer.tooltip.contentGenerator(function (d) { ... })
```

I hope the answer is useful for you, even if late.

Comment: great answer, very useful.. :-)

Comment: holy hell that was frustrating trying to figure out why chart.tooltip wasn't working

Answer (score 15):

Customized tooltip can not exist with "useInteractiveGuideline".

Comment: It's now possible to have custom content with interactive guidelines as of version 1.8.1 (https://github.com/novus/nvd3/tree/v1.8.1-alpha).

Answer (score 8):

If you happen to use the [Angular NVD3](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/) wrapper, the way to set the custom message is through chart options, simply:

```
$scope.options = {
  chart: {
  ...
  tooltip: {
      contentGenerator: function(d) {
          return d.series[0].key + ' ' + d.series[0].value;
      }
  },
  ...
  }
};
```

Comment: you're a savior!

Answer (score 5):

To add to previous answers, sometimes you want to use the data of the series and not only of `x` and `y`. For instance when

```
data = {'values': [{'month': 1, 'count': 2}, ...], 'key': 'test' }
```

For those situations, use

```
.tooltip(function(key, x, y, e, graph) {
         var d = e.series.values[e.pointIndex];
         return '<h3>' + e.series.key + '</h3><p>' + d.month.toString() + ...;
 });
```

`e.series` is the particular series the mouse is hovering, `e.pointIndex` is the index on the values of the series. Here `e.series.key == key`, but I used to empathise what is `e.series`.

Comment: Would you take a moment to look at my question here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64051027/how-to-add-more-attributes-in-tooltip-series-in-angular-nvd3-line-chart

What you say is very close to what I want to achieve, and your data structure is exactly what I have, but my function(d) has only one argument - d, and I am unable to reach to the custom attributes in values array via the d argument.

Answer (score 4):

```
my_chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
  .tooltip(function(key, x, y, e, graph) {
    return '<h3>' + key + '</h3>' +
           '<p>' +  y + ' on ' + x + '</p>';
  });
```

Comment: Just voted this from -1 to 0. Why was it downvoted? This was helpful.

Comment: it wasn't me, but I'd guess it's because the answer is incorrect - the question was about piecharts, and tooltip doesn't work for pie, it has to be tooltipContent and there shouldn't be an x parameter

Comment: While the question may have been directed at pie charts I was thankful this was added in. My search was more general.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing the 'x' parameter in your tooltip function. The format of the function call is:

```
function(key, x, y, e, graph)
```

Comment: this is incorrect - there's no x parameter in pie charts; the problem is that it should be .tooltipContent as in user1847371's answer

Answer (score 1):

```
var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart();

chart.tooltip.contentGenerator(function (obj) {
                return JSON.stringify("<b>HOHO</b>")
            })
```

This worked for me...

Answer (score -2):

```js
chart:{
interactive:true,
tooltips: true,
tooltip: {
  contentGenerator: function (d) {
    return '<h3>PUT YOUR DATA HERE E.g. d.data.name</h3>'
  }
}
```

Thank You and Best Regards
Abhay Patidar

Comment: Please edit your answer, or you could be down-voted. As it is now, it's just a suggestion with no context. Please see here for [How to Write a Good Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) on StackOverflow.