# Using variables in NVD3 Tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip, nvd3.js

I'm using an NVD3 multiBarHorizontalChart to display some stacked data. Each series is a type of record and then the values are the number of records which meet a certain criteria.

I would like to modify the tooltip so that the value shows how many met the criteria out of the total number of records that type so "33 / 100" rather than "33" as now.

I've seen [nvd3 piechart.js - How to edit the tooltip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416508/nvd3-piechart-js-how-to-edit-the-tooltip) and have added the value to the json I'm passing to the datum parameter but I'm not sure how to reference that in the function.

Comment: can you add your code sample ?

Comment: I think your data element is `e` in that question you've linked to.

Comment: Ahh - I've logged e to the console and can see it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attributes of the series are stored in e.series

In my case having passed a total variable into the Json I've modified multiBarHorizontalChart.js so that the function now looks like:

```
tooltip = function(key, x, y, e, graph) {
    return '<h3>' + key + ' - ' + x + '</h3>' +
           '<p>' +  y + '/' + e.series.total + '</p>'
  }
```

Comment: Accept your answer so it will help others.