# NVD3 TooltipContent Does not work

Tags: tooltip, nvd3.js

I am using NVD3 library for my project and i have written following code.

```
var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
            .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
            .margin({top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50})
            .tooltipContent(function (key, y, e, graph) {
                console.log("helo");
                return "hello";
            });
```

Expected output should be to show hello on mouse over.
But i dont get that, instead i get the default tooltip.

Please let me know the mistake i am doing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [nvd3 piechart.js - How to edit the tooltip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416508/nvd3-piechart-js-how-to-edit-the-tooltip)

Comment: I got it now the line .useInteractiveGuideline(true) is not correct. it should be .useInteractiveGuideline(false). As Customized tooltip can not exist with "useInteractiveGuideline" suggested by user2612936 on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416508/nvd3-piechart-js-how-to-edit-the-tooltip

Comment: Thanks shabeer90 for directing to the right post.

Answer (score 14):

It's now possible to have custom content with interactive guidelines as of version 1.8.1 (https://github.com/novus/nvd3/tree/v1.8.1-alpha).

```
chart.interactiveLayer.tooltip.contentGenerator(function(data) {
    return 'this is my custom content';
});
```

Comment: Thanks.
This works for angular-nvd3 too.
`interactiveLayer:{
                        tooltip: {
                            contentGenerator: function(data) {
                                console.log('tooltip', data);
                            }
                        }
                    }`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer... saved me a lot of time as it is not written on the docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Starting with nvd3 version 1.8+ use the method `chart.tooltip.contentGenerator()`
instead of `.tooltipContent()`

For example:

```
  chart.tooltip.contentGenerator(function(data) {
      return '<p>' + data.point.x + '</p>'
  }
```

More info here - https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/1359

Answer (score 0):

Could you please create a fiddle or plunkr for it?
Below is implementation of our project code, it returns an html element an works well:

```
.tooltipContent(function (key, x, y, e) {
                            if (e.value >= 0) {
                                return '<h3>' + key + '</h3>' +
                                    '<p>' + y + ' at ' + x + '</p>';
                            } else {
                                return '';
                            }
                        });
```