# NVD3 Line Graph - Custom Tooltip values from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am having a lot of trouble trying to get part of my JSON values to show when hovering over a datapoint.

This is the data I'm using below -

```
 var datax = [{"key":"IOVN","values":[{"x":0,"y":387.3,"z":"01640"},{"x":1,"y":387.3,"z":"01640"},{"x":2,"y":387.3,"z":"01640"},{"x":3,"y":387,"z":"01166"},{"x":4,"y":387.3,"z":"01959"},{"x":5,"y":387.3,"z":"01959"},{"x":6,"y":387.3,"z":"01959"}]},{"key":"IOVX","values":[{"x":0,"y":387.3,"z":"01640"},{"x":1,"y":387.3,"z":"01640"},{"x":2,"y":387.3,"z":"01640"},{"x":3,"y":388,"z":"01166"},{"x":4,"y":387.3,"z":"01959"},{"x":5,"y":387.3,"z":"01959"},{"x":6,"y":387.3,"z":"01959"}]}];
```

I would like to show the "z" value when hovering over a datapoint that shows the tooltip.

I've tried all kinds of things but can't seem to find anything online how to do it?

Could anyone shed some light-

here is the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kd82ep7p/5/

Comment: Have you taken a look at this [**question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416508/nvd3-piechart-js-how-to-edit-the-tooltip) ?

Comment: Yes this kind of works but not in the way I want it to, I want it to work with the ineractive guideline like in my example